# Got multiple values for keyword argument 'label'

Tags: python, flask, label, textarea, flask-wtforms

I am trying to set a custom label for submit, not sure why I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'label'
```

---

```
class Reply(Form):
    body = TextAreaField([Length(50, 1000)])
    submit = SubmitField()

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.body.kwargs['label'] = lazy_gettext(u'Public comment of %(value)s', value=user)
        Form.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

If I change to the code below, then everything works fine:

```
body = TextAreaField()
```

It seems that there's some conflict with `[Length(50, 1000)]` and the custom `label`.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to dynamically populate values in your form is in the route, not in the form's init method.

```
def reply():
    form = Reply(request.form)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Use form contents
        return redirect(url_for('reply'))

    user = get_user()
    form.body.label.text = f'Public comment of {user}'

    return render_template('reply.html', form=form)
```